# MS Access SQL Query statement

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

This statement needs to get a list of emails for some friends to volunteer. I need the WHERE clause to return from the list of checkboxes only those volunteers with an email also. The following code only works when the IsVolunteer checkbox is checked and the Has an Email is checked. What is wrong with the SQL statement?

So the result should be like...
Bill Turner... bturner@gmail.com... and show those checked volunteer items to requery in the form. Only those who have emails should be in this view.

```
If Abs(Me.hasEmailCkb.Value) = 1 And Abs(Me.CheckIsVol.Value) = 1 Then
VolToEMail = "Select * from [Members] where ([Food] = true Or [Setup] = true Or [Carpool] = true Or [Mail] = true AND [Email] <> NULL) Order By [LName] ASC"
Me.Members_subform.Form.RecordSource = VolToEMail
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses *before* the `AND`:

```
Select *
from [Members]
where ([Food] = true Or [Setup] = true Or [Carpool] = true Or [Mail] = true) AND 
      ([Email] IS NOT NULL)
Order By [LName] ASC;
```

Note that `<> NULL` should be `IS NOT NULL`.  `<> NULL` will always return `NULL`, which is treated as false.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND [Email] <> NULL
```

This does not work. You need to use:

```
AND [Email] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Still not working. It gives me the nulls. Perhaps it is because the way the or and and clauses are arrayed in sequence.